# Detach keyboard from the kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, keyboard

I am writing a remote controller app for an octocopter and want to use a keyboard as an input device for this app but I don't want it to have any effect outside this app. Somehow I would like to make the kernel to see this keyboard as one of the input devices (like a gamepad) but not treat it as a keyboard.

I searched for the answer but found only solutions at Xorg level but I want to do it at a lower level to disable even the SysRq commands.

(I use Linux Mint 16 and a noname usb keyboard)

Comment: You can globally disable sysrq commands by recompiling your kernel with them turned off.

Comment: It was just an example. I want to prevent every possible conflict with other apps.